# Initializing a class using threading (Python)

Tags: python, multithreading, class, python-2.7

So I have this code

```
import socket
def main():
    #does a bunch of argument parsing
while True:
     newsock, fromaddr = s.accept()
     ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(newsock, server_side=True)
     threading.Thread(target=tls_listener, args=(ssl_sock,)).start()

def tls_listener(ssl_sock):
     #the thing I want to turn into a class
     #calls other functions, does some reporting 



if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

I want to make the tls_listener a class (it's grown quite a bit, and I've realized I should abstract it (and use `self` as opposed to passing variables)), but am not sure how to start up instances of a class using threading, as it needs to be passed a function. Should I do something like

```
class TlsListener(threading):
    #overload run()
```

or would it be possible to have the thread create new instances of a TlsListener class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to create a new instance of the `TlsListener` class each time you accept a socket, you can simply leave your code as is, and create a new class inside of `tls_listener` function:

```
while True:
     newsock, fromaddr = s.accept()
     ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(newsock, server_side=True)
     threading.Thread(target=tls_listener, args=(ssl_sock,)).start()

def tls_listener(ssl_sock):
    t = TlsListener()  # new instance of TlsListener class
```

Comment: I can't actually upvote this answer, as I have less than 15 reputation, but thank you! Very simple, elegant solution.